# Accessing Files in Team Foundation Server Version Control Without Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

How can I access files held in TFS source control without installation of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [Team Explorer Everywhere](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-explorer-everywhere) as an alternative way to get at your Team Foundation source code.

The actual source code is stored in a SQL Server database that the Team Foundation Server installs.

Comment: There are lots of table :) are they seperated in different tables??

Comment: Yes, and that's why you should use **a tool** to access TFS - don't try to hack this yourself!! There's also a [Team Foundation SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to get access to TFS and its sources

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the Team Explorer installation (included with the TFS install) will install enough of Visual Studio to access TFS. It also installs the command line tool (`tf.exe`) which can be used to perform most operations without needing to start Visual Studio.

Installing the TFS PowerToys will optionally add a PowerSehll module that includes cmdlets for most version control operations, and integrates nicely into PowerShell.

On other OSs look at [Team Explorer Everywhere](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-explorer-everywhere) (as [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167488/accessing-files-in-team-foundation-server-version-control-without-visual-studio/5167573#5167573) has already answered).